# Django REST Framework strange results

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For some reason, I'm getting some weird problems with sending a `POST` request.

This is my URL settings:

```
http://host/api/user/1/edit/
http://host/api/address/search/
```

Where `/api/` is the API-Root, user is a model, 1 is user ID, and `edit` and `search` are custom functions.

This is inside `views.py`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        ... (processing)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def edit(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        ... (processing)

class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... (processing)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... (processing)
```

This is inside `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'address', views.AddressViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^authentication/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

The strange thing I'm encountering is this:

If I'm using `httpie` and sending a `POST` edit request like this:

```
http POST http://host/api/user/1/edit/ name="john" address="google.com"
```

Then the stuff inside `def post` will never get executed. This is the same if I make the browser send a `POST` request.

However, if I send a `POST` search request by doing:

```
http POST http://host/api/address/search/ name="john"
```

Then in this case the stuff inside `def search` will never get executed, while only the stuff inside `def post` will get executed.

The only difference I can see is that for `edit`, there's an extra `pk` (value of `1` for this example), while there are no `pk` for `search.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's really confusing for me

Comment: I'm curious how do you send `POST` data using browser?

Comment: I used Jquery AJAX to send it

Comment: Can you try curl in your shell: `curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "john", "address": "google.com"}' http://host/api/user/1/edit/`?

Comment: It seems to be fine. Returns the same thing as if I do it using `POST`

Answer (score 2):

Defining post() in a ViewSet doesn't do anything, this is for APIView derived classes. If you want to override default object creation in a ViewSet you can either

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ... do stuff ...
```

or even better

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    ... do stuff ...
    serializer.save()
```

As for the address, you need to use list_route decorator instead of detail_route. detail_route is for operating on an individual object and list_route is for lists. So /address/search/ should be list route and /address/1/search/ would be a detail_route. Mind you that I don't think your code in post() runs in either case.

Here is a relevant piece of docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: I'm 100% sure the code runs when I'm doing `search`. I've tried to put just `Response("post")` in post, and `Response("function")` and run it twice to test.

Comment: Your post might be missing something from your actual code. If the code is structured the way you posted, nothing is going to call post(). Given you are on a recent version of REST framework. Anyway, try my suggestions.

Comment: It's from here, something like this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: Yes, you might notice that post() is not in the list of pre-defined methods on that page. post() is for APIView, not ViewSet.

Comment: Sorry, I mislinked it: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions

Comment: Yes, and this link tells you exactly what I said, use detail_route and list_route decorators to add extra actions to your API :)

Answer (score 1):

When submitting a post request to rest framework the request is mapped to methods on the ViewSet, unlike Django views that simply call the `post` method.

When posting to `user/{pk}/` your request is mapped to the `UserViewSet.create` method. A post request to `user/{pk}/edit/` maps to your `UserViewSet.edit` method. In both cases, `UserViewSet.post` is not called.

It seems that when you post to a custom url that doesn't exist the `post` method is called instead (probably as a fallback). In your case `address/search/` isn't a valid url, and instead you've defined an endpoint as `address/{pk}/search/`.

If you want to access `address/search/` you need to update your search method to use a `list_route` decorator instead of `detail_route`:

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... (processing)
```

Hope this helps to clear things up for you.